# Import garmin Topo map to QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, garmin

I would like to import my Garmin Topo Maps to QGIS. I want to use the Topo Map as a Layer to create Shapefiles.

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to import the Garmin maps including waypoints as a vector layer in QGIS?

Comment: @AndreJoost  Thanks for the reply . I have removed my comment.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I`m afraid Garmin's copyright protection only allows to use their Topo map with BaseCamp and Mapsource.

You can digitize them by creating GPX files with that software, and import those files into QGIS. This might not work on Linux Operating systems.

Anyway, digitizing from official Topo maps is much easier, if the authorities offer them as a WMS service.